# Is this possible to pass multiple values at once for fetching process instances by passing variables?

Tags: alfresco, activiti, alfresco-enterprise

I am fetching process instances by passing the variables. I am using **historic process instance query** api.

**Reference link is as follows:**

http://localhost:8082/activiti-app/api-explorer.html#!/process-instances/getHistoricProcessInstancesUsingPOST

**Curl command for this API is as follows:**

curl -X POST --header 'Content-Type: application/json' --header 'Accept: application/json' --header 'Authorization: Basic YWRtaW5AYXBwLmFjdGl2aXRpLmNvbTphZG1pbg==' -d '{ \ 
   "variables": [
     {
       "name": "location",
       "operation": "equals",
       "value": "banglore"
     }
   ]
 }' 'http://localhost:8082/activiti-app/api/enterprise/historic-process-instances/query'

The above example worked for me. But I want to pass multiple values at once for the value. **For example,** I need to pass **India, Banglore, Puna, Delhi etc**... as **values** for the **value** at once. Is this possible to pass multiple values to the value at once. Can any one provide solution in this?

Thanks & Regards

Shilpa Kulkarni

Comment: this looks a bit tricky, but can you try multiple objects with same `name` and `operation` but different `value`. e.g. `{"variables":[{"name": "location","operation": "equals","value": "banglore"}, {"name": "location","operation": "equals","value": "pune"}]}`. please let us know if that works :)

Comment: Yes I already tried like this but I am not getting any records but still response code is 200.